# How many nodes have only one child in a binary tree?

Tags: c, recursion, struct, tree, binary-tree

I want to calculate how many nodes from a binary tree have only one child. I don't know if this is ok. Also I don't know if I have to use a tree search like postorder.

```
size_t tree_one_child(const tree_t* t){
if(!t || number_children(t)==0){
    return 0;
}
if(number_children(t)==1){
    return 1 + tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
}
else{
    return tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
}



size_t number_children(const tree_t* t){
int count = 0;
if(t->left != null ) count++;
if(t->right != null) count++;       
return count;
}
```

Comment: Do you consider only the immediate child or any "grandchildren" as well?

Comment: This looks okay.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Just the immediate child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some remarks on your code:**

You could simplify `if(!t || number_children(t)==0)` to just `if(!t)`.

To avoid repeating yourself, you should save the recursive calculation of the children in a variable:

```
size_t tree_one_child(const tree_t* t){
    if(!t)
        return 0;

    size_t ret = tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
    if (number_children(t) == 1)
        ret++;
    return ret;
}
```

Unless you're using `number_children` somewhere else, you could use this instead:

```
size_t one_child(const tree_t* t){
    return !t->left != !t->right;
}
```

The expression `!a != !b` is a way to perform a logical xor, which is exactly what you want here. It makes the code a bit cleaner.

```
size_t tree_one_child(const tree_t* t){
    if(!t)
        return 0;

    size_t ret = tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
    if (one_child(t))
        ret++;
    return ret;
}
```

To make this code shorter, you could do like this:

```
size_t tree_one_child(const tree_t* t){
    if(!t)
        return 0;
    return one_child(t) + tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
}
```

Some may argue that this id bad practice, since addition between a Boolean value (I know that `one_child` technically returns a size_t, but it's obviously meant to be considered as true/false) does not really make sense. It just happens to work because it returns 1 on true and 0 on false.

**Will your code work?**

As far as I can see, it seems to do the job, and I cannot see any case where it produce the wrong result or do anything bad.

An advice on what you could do to convince yourself is to write tests. I'll give a quick guide to how to do it.

First, create a function `create_tree( .. )` that creates a tree from it's arguments. Maybe you could have a function that takes just a `char*` and do some magic with that string to produce a tree. That way you could have some tests like this:

```
void test(char * s, int expected_output) {
    tree_t * t = create_tree(s)  
    if(tree_one_child(t) == expected_output)
        printf("Test passed\n");
    else
        printf("   TEST FAILED");
    deallocate_tree(t);
}

test("1332", 3);
test("10423", 0);
```

**Note** There are fairly standardized methods to do this, but I guess you get the idea. Find some way to make it easy to test your code and test it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are missing the closing brace to the function tree_one_child(), but apart from that, this code will work.

A style note though: in general, it's better to only have one place that does a particular job, such as calculating the number of one-child nodes below you; you do it in two places.  Granted, when the work is as simple as `recurse(left) + recurse(right)` it's pretty safe.  But I would have written this routine as

```
size_t tree_one_child(const tree_t* t) {
    if (t == NULL)
        return 0;
    return number_children(t) + tree_one_child(t->left) + tree_one_child(t->right);
}
```

I think this is both safer (in that it is impossible that anyone will some day modify the logic for some of the nodes but not others) and clearer.

Comment: I realize that I forgot to motivate my downvote. Your code does not work properly. It will give twe wrong answer for nodes with two nodes. You need to change `number_children(t)` to `(number_children(t) == 1)`. Not sure if the parenthesis are needed. I just add them to be sure. Fix that, and I'll upvote your answer instead.